# problem fetching number of days in a month in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, date, calendar

i have a chain of year, month start day and end days select elements .. 
years and ofcourse months are available but the problem is with the number of days of the selected month to be selected from, as the start day !

i am using this in the JS file 
`days = new Date(2010, 4, 0).getDate(); // returns 29` , which is supposed to be 30 !

where is the problem, i made sure of the days in each month by php cal_days_in_month(0, 4, 2010) which returns 30

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just accept the date is 1-based, a small trick would give you the number of days of a given month:

```
function getDaysForMonth(m,y){
  var datebase = new Date(y,m,1); //nb: month = zerobased
  datebase.setDate(datebase.getDate()-1);
  return datebase.getDate();
}
```

Let's take it for some februari's:

```
var feb2000 = getDaysForMonth(2,2000); //=> 29
var feb2004 = getDaysForMonth(2,2004); //=> 29
var feb2008 = getDaysForMonth(2,2008); //=> 29
var feb2010 = getDaysForMonth(2,2010); //=> 28
```

You can make a Date.prototype method for it:

```
Date.prototype.daysThisMonth = function(){
 var x = new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth()+1,1);
 x.setDate(x.getDate()-1);
 return x.getDate();
};
//usage
var d1 = new Date('2010/2/23').daysThisMonth() //=> 28
//nb new Date('2010/2/23') in your notation: new Date(2010,1,23)
```

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but new Date('2010/04/23').daysThisMonth() = 30 here;

Answer (score 0):

I use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). It has numerous handy date functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
new Date(2010, 4, 0)
```

...is incorrect; it may work in some implementations but not others. The `Date` constructor takes year, month, day, hour, minute, and second (everything but `year` and `month` are optional, because if you use a one-argument constructor, it assumes you're giving a milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value), and month is 0-based but day is 1-based (yes, really — hey, I didn't design it). So the first of April is `new Date(2010, 3, 1)` (`0` = January, `1` = February, `2` = March, `3` = April) and there is no day-of-month `0` (according to Section 15.9.1.5 of the spec, the range is 1..31).

Comment: Thanks but i didn't really get your point !:) , here is where i got the code : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-days-in-month/

Comment: @Dewan: My point is that `new Date(2010, 4, 0)` is invalid and could return anything. The third value cannot be `0` (according to spec, must be `1` to `31` inclusive), which means you get whatever you get and can't trust it.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome  it just outputs 30:

> document.write( days = new Date(2010, 4, 0).getDate());

Comment: firefox 3.6.13 /w firebug 1.6: new Date(2010,4,0).getDate() = 30

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the next month as the argument because it moves backwards when the day is 0:

```
new Date(2012, 1, 0); //returns Jan not Feb
```

If this is something that you use often, create a function

```
function getDaysOfMonth(year, month){
   return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate()
}
```